# curl is stuck when trying to get NameNodeStatus

Tags: linux, networking, curl, http, hadoop

we have two namenode in the cluster hadoop cluster

this is good example of one of the name node that return good status

first namenode machine IP - `92.3.44.2`

```
curl -v http://92.3.44.2:50070/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus
* About to connect() to 92.3.44.2 port 50070 (#0)
*   Trying 92.3.44.2...
* Connected to 92.3.44.2 (92.3.44.2) port 50070 (#0)
> GET /jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 92.3.44.2:50070
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Expires: Mon, 27 Jan 2020 15:39:57 GMT
< Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2020 15:39:57 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Mon, 27 Jan 2020 15:39:57 GMT
< Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2020 15:39:57 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Jetty(6.1.26.hwx)
<
{
  "beans" : [ {
    "name" : "Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus",
    "modelerType" : "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode",
    "State" : "active",
    "NNRole" : "NameNode",
    "HostAndPort" : "namenode.kuku.com:8020",
    "SecurityEnabled" : false,
    "LastHATransitionTime" : 1579019610100,
    "BytesWithFutureGenerationStamps" : 0,
    "SlowPeersReport" : null,
    "SlowDisksReport" : null
  } ]
* Connection #0 to host 92.3.44.2 left intact
```

but on the second name node the picture is diff

example

```
curl -v http://92.3.44.3:50070/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus
* About to connect() to 92.3.44.3 port 50070 (#0)
*   Trying 92.3.44.3...
* Connected to 92.3.44.2 (92.3.44.2) port 50070 (#0)
> GET /jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 92.3.44.2:50070
> Accept: */*
>
```

we can see that command curl is stuck

how to identify why curl is stuck ?

Comment: According to your post, `curl` was able to connect and had sent the request but had not received a response.  It is likely your server located at that address is hanging.  You would want to look at the logs of that server to see if the request was received and why it does not respond.

Comment: please give me please more details , how to debug the problem? ( which logs ? )

Comment: You would probably start at the Hadoop logs on that server.  If nothing interesting is there, check the system logs.  More detail would require additional details in your question.  Providing the distributions used would allow users to point out specific log locations.  Providing the state of the server could open more lines of diagnostics.  Are you able to connect to that machine and get a response from it?  Does `uptime` show a high load?

Comment: curl output looks strange `*   Trying 92.3.44.3...
* Connected to 92.3.44.2 (92.3.44.2) port 50070 (#0)` Who/how redirected it to 44.2 from 44.3?

Comment: You may also want to open up a browser and point it to `http://92.3.44.3:50070/jmx`